# SwiftUI UndoManager — how does it work and isn't it working?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, nsundomanager

I'm trying to learn how UndoManager works. I made a small app to Undo/Redo something.
And I have few questions, I cannot find answer in documentation:

1. I know UndoManager could be accessed in View via

   `@Environment(\.undoManager) var undoManager`

Brilliant. But in this case it's only available in a View, if I want use it somewhere deeper in a structure I have to pass it via Model to Objects... Is a way to access the same UndoManager in other objects? Models, Data... I could be much more convenient, specially if there is many Undo groupings. If I create UndoManager in Document (or somewhere else) it's not visible for main menu Edit -> Undo, Redo

2. In the app [repository on GitHub](https://github.com/typoland/LookingForUndo) I implemented Undo/Redo. For me (*haha*) it looks OK and even works, but not for first action. First action Undo causes `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` error. After three actions I can undo two last actions... Bang. Something is wrong

   ```
    import Foundation
    import SwiftUI

    struct CustomView: View {
        @ObservedObject var model: PointsViewModel

        @Environment(\.undoManager) var undoManager

        @GestureState var isDragging: Bool = false
        @State var dragOffsetDelta = CGPoint.zero

        var formatter: NumberFormatter {
            let formatter = NumberFormatter()
            formatter.allowsFloats = true
            formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
            formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 5
            return formatter
        }

        var body: some View {
            HStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                    ForEach(model.insideDoc.points.indices, id:\.self) { index in
                        HStack {
                            TextField("X", value: $model.insideDoc.points[index].x, formatter: formatter)
                                .frame(width: 80, alignment: .topLeading)
                            TextField("Y", value: $model.insideDoc.points[index].y, formatter: formatter)
                                .frame(width: 80, alignment: .topLeading)
                            Spacer()
                        }

                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            ZStack {
                ForEach(model.insideDoc.points.indices, id:\.self) { index in
                    Circle()
                        .foregroundColor(index == model.selectionIndex ? .red : .blue)
                        .frame(width: 20, height: 20, alignment: .center)
                        .position(model.insideDoc.points[index])

                        //MARK: - drag point
                        .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .local)
                                    .onChanged { drag in
                                        if !isDragging {
                                            dragOffsetDelta = drag.location - model.insideDoc.points[index]
                                            model.selectionIndex = index
                                            let now = model.insideDoc.points[index]
                                            undoManager?.registerUndo(withTarget: model, handler: { model in
                                                model.insideDoc.points[index] = now
                                                model.objectWillChange.send()
                                            })
                                            undoManager?.setActionName("undo Drag")
                                        }
                                        model.insideDoc.points[index] = drag.location - dragOffsetDelta
                                    }
                                    .updating($isDragging, body: { drag, state, trans in
                                        state = true
                                        model.objectWillChange.send()
                                    })
                                    .onEnded({drag in model.selectionIndex = index
                                        model.insideDoc.points[index] = drag.location - dragOffsetDelta
                                        model.objectWillChange.send()
                                    })
                        )

                }
            }.background(Color.orange.opacity(0.5))

            //MARK: - new point
            .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .local)
                        .onEnded{ loc in
                            let previousIndex = model.selectionIndex
                            undoManager?.registerUndo(withTarget: model, handler: {model in
                                model.insideDoc.points.removeLast()
                                model.selectionIndex = previousIndex
                                model.objectWillChange.send()
                            })
                            model.insideDoc.points.append(loc.location)
                            model.selectionIndex = model.insideDoc.points.count - 1
                            model.objectWillChange.send()
                        }

            )

            //MARK: - delete point
            .onReceive(deleteSelectedObject, perform: { _ in
                if let deleteIndex = model.selectionIndex {
                    let deleted = model.insideDoc.points[deleteIndex]
                    undoManager?.registerUndo(withTarget: model, handler: {model in
                        model.insideDoc.points.insert(deleted, at: deleteIndex)
                        model.objectWillChange.send()
                    })
                    undoManager?.setActionName("remove Point")
                    model.insideDoc.points.remove(at: deleteIndex)
                    model.objectWillChange.send()
                    model.selectionIndex = nil
                }
            })

        }
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: Check this really awesome and well explained blog about UndoManager
https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/undomanager-in-swift-5-with-simple-example-8c791e231b87

Comment: I saw it. But this is done in an "old @objc way". What I'm trying is pure SwiftUI, quite different I guess.

Answer (score 6):

Just stumbled on this while looking for something else, and I thought I'd share my own experience. In my application, I was tearing my hair out about the sometimes presence of an UndoManager and my debugging revealed that over the lifespan of a given View, the undo manager could *change*. I store the UndoManager in a global state object so that everything the app does can (potentially) be registered for undo. So now I wind up with code like this:

```swift
struct MyView: View {
  @Environment(\.undoManager) var undoManager
  @ObservedObject var applicationStateModel ...
...
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
...
    }
    .onChange(of: undoManager) { newManager in
      applicationStateModel.undoManager = newManager
    }
    .onAppear {
      applicationStateModel.undoManager = undoManager
    }
  }
}
```